# is(:visible) returning true even though overlay is hidden jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

I have a script that I need to run only an overlay is not visible.

So I have used the following script:

Example below, button shows/hides overlay. Console logs result

```js
function overlay() {
  if( $('div#overlay').is(':visible') ){
        console.log("visible");
 }
 else {
     console.log("not visible");
    }
};
```

```css
#overlay {
     visibility: hidden;
     position: fixed;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:40%;
     height: 40%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 1000;
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: orange;
     /*Flexbox*/
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     align-content: center;
     justify-content: center;
}

form.overlay-form {
     width:780px;
}
table.overlay-table {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
table.overlay-table tr td {
 background: rgb(54, 25, 25); 
 background: rgba(54, 25, 25, 0); 
 border-style: none;
 margin-right: 40%;
 margin-bottom: 30%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 width: 800px;
}
.button {
  z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay">
    Overlay showing
</div>
</br></br></br></br>
</br></br></br></br>
<input id="clickMe" class="button" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="overlay();" />
```

> **EDIT**: following correcting . for # due to it being an id not a class. Now, when my overlay is **NOT** on the screen. It returns
>   'visible'.

This script **always returns** "visible". Help!!

Thanks

Comment: You are using `$('div.overlay')`, but the div has an **id**, it should be `$('div#overlay')`

Comment: I had the same problem with $(elem).is(':visible') returning true when the element's style was visibility: hidden. you also need to set the element's style to display: none and is(':visible') will work as "expected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use `if( $('div#overlay').is(':visible')){` because `overlay` is `id` not `class`:-

```
if( $('div#overlay').is(':visible')){
   console.log("visible");
}else {
   console.log("not visible");
}
```

***For answer your current question use `if( el.style.visibility =='visible' ){` like below:-***

```js
function overlay() {
 el = document.getElementById("overlay");
 el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
  if( el.style.visibility =='visible' ){
        console.log("visible");
 }
 else {
     console.log("not visible");
    }
};
```

```css
#overlay {
     visibility: hidden;
     position: fixed;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:40%;
     height: 40%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 1000;
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: orange;
     /*Flexbox*/
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     align-content: center;
     justify-content: center;
}

form.overlay-form {
     width:780px;
}
table.overlay-table {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}
table.overlay-table tr td {
 background: rgb(54, 25, 25); 
 background: rgba(54, 25, 25, 0); 
 border-style: none;
 margin-right: 40%;
 margin-bottom: 30%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 width: 800px;
}
.button {
  z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay">
    Overlay showing
</div>
</br></br></br></br>
</br></br></br></br>
<input id="clickMe" class="button" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="overlay();" />
```

Reason:-

Based on documentation:-https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

***Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.***

Since overlay div have always get `visibility:hidden` so basically it's space is there and that's why `:visible` always return true.

If you want to use `:visible` then do `display:none;` and `display:block;`

Comment: @RuthYoung  glad to help you

Comment: @RuthYoung  i have added the reason too why that happens?

Comment: setting an element to visibility:hidden without also using display:none; will cause is(':visible') to return true

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there with a small mistake. Since `overlay` is id,

```
if( $('div.overlay').is(':visible')){
    console.log("visible");
}
```

Should be

```
if( $('div#overlay').is(':visible')){
    console.log("visible");
}
```